# How to find the second occurrence of the same character in an Excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need a formula that returns the text after the second underscore in a cell.  How would you find the text after the second underscore below (ELXP1):

Canada_CBA38MV_ELXP1

Here is the formula I'm using right now but not working perfectly

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("_",A2)-FIND("_",A2))
```

Comment: You have the `[excel-vba]` tag, do you really want a VBA answer?  (I ask because there's a really simple answer in VBA).

Comment: I included the VBA tag just incase anyone had a good VBA solution but simple formulas work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Us MID and SUBSTITUTE:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_","}}}",2))+1,LEN(A2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you were trying for something like this where you find the second character and then extract everything to the right of that:

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("_",A2,FIND("_",A2)+1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

Actually, this formula will extract everything after the **LAST** occurrence of the designated character.  If there might be more than two, and you still want everything after the 2nd, the formula can be modified.

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",REPT(" ",99)),99*2,LEN(A1)))
```